# Force an image to scale up to a certain pixel size in imageJ?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagej, imagej-macro

I have an image processing script that find particles in frames and crops them. I'm a bit new to imageJ, and so I can easily find ways to crop it into a square such that the maximum is, say, 64x64 pixels, but I also need a way to make any crops smaller than 64x64 scale up. I don't particularly care what fills the rest of the space, although if there was a way to copy, say, the rightmost column of pixels, that would probably be better. Are there any pre-built macros that will let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about filling the rest of the space, I should think that the Adjust/Canvas Size... should work, at least in 2D.  Copying a specific set of pixels to fill the rest of the space would be something you'd likely have to build yourself.